# Oracle : select last updated row having maximum DATE_COLUMN

Tags: java, sql, oracle

suppose I have a oracle table like this.

```
EMP_ID    DATE_EX       ATTN   LEV   REV
--------  -----------   ----   ----  ----
50001000  13-07-2017    22     02    1
50001000  19-08-2017    26     04    2
50001001  30-06-2017    20     05    3
50001000  17-09-2017    20     05    4
50001000  19-08-2017    25     05    5
50001001  27-07-2017    21     04    6
50001000  17-09-2017    26     02    7
50001000  13-07-2017    21     04    8
```

I want to get the last updated single row with maximum DATE_EX and maximum REV.

and my expected output would be

### output:

```
EMP_ID    DATE_EX       ATTN   LEV   REV
--------  -----------   ----   ----  ----
50001000  17-09-2017    26     02    7
```

I am looking for an efficient sql query. Please help..
The query must be compatible oracle 10g

Comment: Please state the problem more clearly. It seems: you want max DATE_EX. If two (or more) DATE_EX are equal to the max, you want a second preference, max by REV (among the max DATE_EX rows only). Then: Is it also possible that REV will be equal (for the same DATE_EX, equal to the max)? If so, then which of the (two or more) rows with equal, maximum DATE_EX and maximum REV for that DATE_EX do you need to select?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.date_ex desc, t.rev desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

If you care about performance, you want an index on `(date_ex desc, rev desc)`.

Comment: we should use order by with rownum.. otherwise we get different rownum for the same row.

Comment: Do you have any other solution other than ROWNUM. still I face the same issue

Comment: @anikeshsharma - This query should give you result you wanted, so what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient query - in particular, it does not require a subquery - uses the FIRST/LAST aggregate function, as shown below. This works best when there are no "ties" for the max DATE_EX (max REV when ties for DATE_EX).

```
with
   test_data ( emp_id, date_ex, attn, lev, rev ) as (
     select 50001000, to_date('13-07-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 22, '02', 1 from dual union all
     select 50001000, to_date('19-08-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 26, '04', 2 from dual union all
     select 50001001, to_date('30-06-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 20, '05', 3 from dual union all
     select 50001000, to_date('17-09-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 20, '05', 4 from dual union all
     select 50001000, to_date('19-08-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 25, '05', 5 from dual union all
     select 50001001, to_date('27-07-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 21, '04', 6 from dual union all
     select 50001000, to_date('17-09-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 26, '02', 7 from dual union all
     select 50001000, to_date('13-07-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 21, '04', 8 from dual
   )
--  End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
--  SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select max(emp_id)  keep (dense_rank last order by date_ex, rev) as emp_id,
       max(date_ex)                                              as date_ex,
       max(attn)    keep (dense_rank last order by date_ex, rev) as attn,
       max(lev)     keep (dense_rank last order by date_ex, rev) as lev,
       max(rev)     keep (dense_rank last order by date_ex)      as rev
from   test_data
;

EMP_ID    DATE_EX     ATTN  LEV  REV
--------  ----------  ----  ---  ---
50001000  17-09-2017    26  02     7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle 12.1 or later, it's just:

```
select * from yourtable
order by date_ex desc, rev desc
fetch first row only;
```